# App crashes on orientation change for a TabActivity with ListActivities in it

Tags: android

I have a TabActivity with 4 tabs in it, each has a ListActivity. I added android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" to the manifest file to restrict my app to portrait mode when the orientation changes. This works fine on all screens except the one with TabActivity. The app crashes when I select a row in the ListAcitivity.
Any help on solving this is appreacited..
thanks..

Comment: Could you post some code? Where is the debug error pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

try this code. Please, read this post http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/17/how-to-set-the-different-screen-orientations-for-tabactivity-children-activities

Hope, it help you